# How to set TextInputLayout startIcon to VectorDrawable with multiple paths

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-components-android, android-vectordrawable

I'm unable to set the Android Material `TextInputLayout` `startIcon` to a `VectorDrawable` with multiple paths.

Here's the `VectorDrawable`'s `XML`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000"
        android:pathData="M11,13H13V15H11M11,9H13V11H11M11,17H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,15V13.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 13.5,12A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 15,10.5V9A2,2 0 0,0 13,7H11A2,2 0 0,0 9,9V10.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10.5,12A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 9,13.5V15A2,2 0 0,0 11,17M12,1C5.92,1 1,5.92 1,12C1,18.08 5.92,23 12,23C18.08,23 23,18.08 23,12C23,5.92 18.08,1 12,1M12,19A7,7 0 0,1 5,12A7,7 0 0,1 12,5A7,7 0 0,1 19,12A7,7 0 0,1 12,19Z" />
</vector>
```

It looks like an 8-ball in the Android Studio preview, but when it loads it's just a gray circle.

[image: 8-ball][image: Gray circle]

I've tried making a `LayerList` with two separate `VectorDrawable`s, loading the images programmatically and through `XML`, but none of that worked. The image loads fine into an `ImageView`. Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: Why not just use some of the SVG icons. Check this: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/eight-ball ... If it is still like that then check if the button theme isn't doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by setting it programmatically using the resource identifier of the start icon drawable of the `TextInputLayout` which is `text_input_start_icon`.

To get the resource integer ID use: [`getIdentifer()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) of the Resources class.

```
val startIconViewId = resources.getIdentifier(
    "text_input_start_icon", "id",
    packageName
)
val textInputLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.my_text_input_layout)
val startIconDrawable: CheckableImageButton = textInputLayout.findViewById(startIconViewId)

val view = View(this)
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable)
startIconDrawable.setBackground(view.background)
```

But you also must keep `app:startIconDrawable` set in the xml layout.

> Do you know how to change the size? Changing the XML height and width isn't working. Also, having the startIconDrawable set in XML is causing both icons to appear on my device.

You can change the height & width of the `CheckableImageButton` itself.

```
val layoutParams = startIconDrawable.layoutParams
layoutParams.height = 100
layoutParams.width = 100
startIconDrawable.setBackground(view.background)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to change the size? Changing the XML height and width isn't working. Also, having the startIconDrawable set in XML is causing both icons to appear on my device.

Comment: @MichaelP wish the updated answer targets your issue .. feel free to ask if you still encounter issues; and thanks to accept the answer if it helped solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, wish there was an easier/straightforward way to do this.